# Were the *meraglim* also the *nesi'im*?

Tags: deuteronomy, bamidbar-numbers-book-of, meraglim-spies, bamidbar-parsha, nasi

The *meraglim* were each chosen to represent each tribe. Why wouldn't the *nasi* of each tribe be the representative, as they were during the consecration of the *Mishqan*?

Comment: Why isn't the President of the USA also the Ambassador to France? [and to India, Argentina, Somalia, East Timor...]

Comment: I'm sure there are good reasons, although it's a bit of a strawman argument in that the tribal government wasn't as sophisticated as a modern one might be. Do you know of a beauracracy that existed in the tribes? Because otherwise it's quite an assumption.

Comment: Rashi seems to indicate that they were indeed nesiim and they were concerned that they would lose their status upon entering Eretz Yisroel

Answer (score 5):

I believe some commentators state they were Nesi'im. However, even if they weren't,<sup>1</sup> I think there's a simple explanation as to why the Nesi'im did not go. In at least one case, we know that the Nasi was simply old, perhaps too old to go. I am referring to Elishama ben Amihud, who was the Nasi of Ephraim ([Bamidbar 1:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.1.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) et al) and the grandfather of Yehoshua bin Nun, according to [Divrei Hayamim 1:7:26-27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Chronicles.7.26-27?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi). Yehoshua was already 40 when he left Egypt, so his grandfather may have already been around 80 at the time. That Yehoshua and Kalev could lead armies in battle in their 80's seems to have been out of the ordinary situations, as Kalev seems to point out himself ([Yehoshua 14:6-11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.14.6-11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> "...and Caleb son of Jephunneh the Kenizzite said to him...Now the LORD has preserved me, as He promised. It is forty-five years since the LORD made this promise to Moses, when Israel was journeying through the wilderness; and here I am today, eighty-five years old. I am still as strong today as on the day that Moses sent me; my strength is the same now as it was then, for battle and for activity."

If it was common that people at his age could lead armies to do battle, then there would have been no need for him to note that he was still as strong as he was in his youth.

---

<sup>1</sup> Birkat Asher for example [suggests](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.13.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Birkat_Asher_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.13.2.8&lang2=bi) that the phrase "כל נשיא בהם" simply means that they were prominent people among their tribesmen.